# Currently having a problem with my tag called "Bottom"

Tags: html, css

Basically I'm trying to make a topbar with information on it, I was just about to change my stuff to a list till I noticed "The pink bar" going over the discord icon, how do I go about fixing this problem; the position is set to absolute.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background: #a89ed2
}

.TopBar {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  background: #483467;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#bottom {
  position: absolute;
  background: #ea5773;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  left: 0;
  top: 90%;
}

#media {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 0%;
  top: 0%;
}

#media img {
  width: 15%;
  height: 10%;
}

.wrapper1 {
  padding: 2%
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class=TopBar>
    <div class=wrapper1>
      <div id=bottom></div>
      <div id=media>
        <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/logos-and-brands-3/512/91_Discord_logo_logos-512.png">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class=content></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `id` or `class` with double quotes(**" classname | id "**)

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="TopBar">
      <div class="wrapper1">
        <div id="bottom"></div>
        <div id="media">
          <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/logos-and-brands-3/512/91_Discord_logo_logos-512.png">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Add a specific `height` to topbar and remove `overflow:hidden`

```
.TopBar {
  height: 85px;
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  background: #a89ed2
}
.TopBar {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  background: #483467;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#media {
 width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
#media img {
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
}
#media::before{
  background: #ea5773;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.wrapper1 {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="TopBar">
      <div class="wrapper1">
        <div id="media">
          <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/logos-and-brands-3/512/91_Discord_logo_logos-512.png">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: yeah sorry about that, but I'm trying to find out why the stuff isn't resizing right.

Comment: Yeah, it's like the image doesn't want to resize to the main div size.

Comment: I think I found the problem, do I not need to tag everything within the parent div as a absolute?

Comment: try now this snippet

Comment: `overflow:hidden;` is the hide the image some part.so remove it and give a specfic height to `TopBar`.

Comment: I'm wanting it to resize accordingly to the bar though?

Comment: `wrapper1`  style `padding:2%` is the height of the topbar

Comment: you acn use ::before element for border-bottom to topbar

Comment: Yeah, and the stuff is nested within it?

Comment: I can try it wait sometime.

Comment: can you reduce the size of `#media img ` to width:12%

Comment: I'm wanting the little icon to be resizable based on div size.